# In order traversal binary tree

Tags: java, binary-tree

I am learning java. I saw this code somewhere.
Does the following code traverse it correctly? Is result list being called correctly? Will it append properly?

```
public void traverse(Node<T> input, List<T> resultlist) {
   if (input != null) {
      traverse(input.getLeftNode(), resultlist)

      resultlist.add(input.getValue())

      traverse(input.getRightNode(), resultlist)
   }
}
```

Comment: On the middle line, I think `result` should be `resultlist`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In-order iterator for binary tree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850889/in-order-iterator-for-binary-tree)

Comment: Please add more details about Node class

Comment: Thanks. Changed to resultlist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By asking whether it does do an in-order traversal (*does this do what it is supposed to do*), I'm guessing you just don't understand the difference between the traversals...

**Primer:**

In order to truly understand this, you need to understand an important aspect of data structures: recursion. This is something that you need to grasp. It may take a bit, and after trying different exercises..it will just click.

**Here is a resource for this to get started:**

http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/recursion/explanation-of-recursion/

Now coming to your question of tree traversal, the typical convention is as follows:

**Pre-Order:**

```
traversalFunction(Node)
   doStuffWithNode(Node)   //prechild traversal
   traversalFunction(Node.left)
   traversalFunction(Node.right)
```

**In-Order**

```
traversalFunction(Node)
   traversalFunction(Node.left)
   doStuffWithNode(Node)   //within child traversal
   traversalFunction(Node.right)
```

**Post-Order:**

```
traversalFunction(Node)
   traversalFunction(Node.left)
   traversalFunction(Node.right)
   doStuffWithNode(Node)  //post child traversal
```

So to answer your question...if you have the method that performs an action on the node in between the left and right traversals then **yes** it is an in-order traversal. That is what you are doing.

You can find more information on the traversals here: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal

Now as to the correctness of the rest of your code, I am unsure because you really haven't inputted any information on your Node class or anything.