# How to return an Iterator for Inorder traversal in Binary Tree?

Tags: java, iterator, binary-tree, inorder

I am trying to store my results of Inorder traversal in an LinkedList and retrieve by iterator, but getting null pointer exception while printing my results. I get correct output when I try to do it by recursion and print value in my function. When I recursively try to call `inorderItr(root.left)`, it takes `root` as null. I think, my return statement is not correct, Not sure, below is my code and comments where my code is breaking. Any help and concepts are appreciated. I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850889/in-order-iterator-for-binary-tree), but doesnt help, as I am trying to return an `Iterator`. Again, I am new to Java and `Iterator` concept. TIA.

Edit: I have found the solution, please see the answer below

```
  class TreeNode {

            int data;
            TreeNode left;
            TreeNode right;

            public TreeNode(int d) {
                data = d;
            }

        }

        public class TreeTraversal {
             TreeNode root;

            public TreeTraversal() {
                root = null;
            }

       static List<TreeNode> l = new LinkedList<TreeNode>();
            public static Iterator<TreeNode> inorderItr(TreeNode root) {

                List<TreeNode> l = new LinkedList<TreeNode>();

      //I think I am missing something here
                if (root == null)
                    return

      //This is where my root is null
                inorderItr(root.left);
                l.add(root);
                inorderItr(root.right);

                Iterator<TreeNode> itr = l.iterator();

                return itr;

            }

    //This code works fine
            public static void inorderWorksFine(TreeNode root) {

                if (root == null)
                    return;

                inorder(root.left);
                System.out.print(root.data + " ");
                inorder(root.right);
            }



            public static void main(String args[]) {

                TreeTraversal t = new TreeTraversal();
                t.root = new TreeNode(10);
                t.root.left = new TreeNode(5);
                t.root.left.left = new TreeNode(1);
                t.root.left.right = new TreeNode(7);
                t.root.right = new TreeNode(40);
                t.root.right.right = new TreeNode(50);

                // inorderWorksFine(t.root);
                Iterator<TreeNode> itr = inorderItr(t.root);

                while (itr.hasNext()) {
                    System.out.println(itr.next().data + " ");
                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In-order iterator for binary tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850889/in-order-iterator-for-binary-tree)

Comment: @vinS: I am trying to return an `Iterator`, I have seen that solution. Can you help to make changes in the code above and tell me whats wrong with that?

Comment: I recommend you make a class that implements the iterator interface like has been recommended. You will have a really hard time creating a recursive method that returns a data iterator without resorting to horrendous performance by iterating through the iterator at each recursive step to create a new one. Besides, converting to a different structure (LinkedList) to create a iterator somewhat defeats the purpose of having a Tree if you have an expensive initial outlay cost.

Comment: To be clear, your inorderItr function will not work. You are essentially converting each individual node in the list to a unique LinkedList and recursively returning it's iterator but not doing anything with the recursively returned iterator. What will be returned is an iterator belonging to a LinkedList with a single item (the root). That being said, short of iterating through each Iterator at each recursive stage there isn't much you can do.

Comment: @ZacharyThompson: Thanks for pointing that out, I have created a global LinkedList now, but still if I wish to return an `Iterator`, how would I do?

Comment: A potential solution would be to recursively generate the LinkedList and then use a helper method to obtain the iterator. Again though, I don't see the point of creating a separate Data Structure for the iterator.

Comment: Please give reason for downvote, I am new to this, and I dont want to get blocked out for asking logical questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a helper method for inorder traversal and Global LinkedList and added all my Inorder elements to that list in a separate recursive helper method. That way we can return an Iterator

```
static List<TreeNode> l = new LinkedList<TreeNode>();

    public static Iterator<TreeNode> inorderItr(TreeNode root) {
    recursionInorder(root);
    Iterator<TreeNode> itr = l.iterator();

     return itr;

    }

    public static void recursionInorder(TreeNode node){
        if(node==null)
              return;

        recursionInorder(node.left);
        l.add(node);
        recursionInorder(node.right);
    }
```